# Why do left and right join ignore some values in a query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, right-join

I have a table with 3 columns and these values:

```
col1   col2   col3
-------------------
  1      2      8
  1      3      5
  1     10     15
  2      4      6
  2      9      7
  3      5      6
```

I join a query LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN a grouping and counting query
 for each number (MS-ACCESS).

```
SELECT Col1 AS Num, t1.CON1, t2.CON2, t3.CON3
        FROM
           (((SELECT col1, COUNT(col1) AS CON1 FROM table GROUP BY col1) AS t1
              LEFT JOIN (SELECT col2, COUNT(col2) AS CON2 FROM table GROUP BY col2) AS t2
                         ON t1.col1 = t2.col2)
              LEFT JOIN (SELECT col3, COUNT(col3) AS CON3 FROM table GROUP BY col3) AS t3
                         ON t2.col2 = t3.col3)
        UNION
        SELECT col3 AS Num, t1.CON1, t2.CON2, t3.CON3
        FROM
           (((SELECT col1, COUNT(col1) AS CON1 FROM table GROUP BY col1) AS t1
              RIGHT JOIN (SELECT col2, COUNT(col2) AS CON2 FROM table GROUP BY col2) AS t2
                          ON t1.col1 = t2.col2)
              RIGHT JOIN (SELECT col3, COUNT(col3) AS CON3 FROM table GROUP BY col3) AS t3
                          ON t2.col1 = t3.col3)
```

It results like this:

```
Num  CON1  CON2  CON3
--------------------------
  1    3      
  2    2     1
  3    1     1
  5          1     1
  6                2
  7                1
  8                1
 15                1
```

But this query ignores count of values from column 2 of table

```
Num    CON2
--------------- 
   4       1
   9       1
  10       1
```

What is missing in my query?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? What is your final expected output?

Comment: the count of values (4, 9, 10) of the CON2 column are missing integrating in the final result..

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please DON'T YELL.Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Say how output is a function of input. Don't hope we guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count each value and the number of times in each column, then use `union all` to split the data and then `group by`:

```
select num, sum(col1), sum(col2), sum(col3)
from ((select col1 as num, 1 as col1, 0 as col2, 0 as col3
       from t
      ) union all
      (select col2 as num, 0 as col1, 1 as col2, 0 as col3
       from t
      ) union all
      (select col3 as num, 0 as col1, 0 as col2, 1 as col3
       from t
      )
     ) as x
group by num
order by num;
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives correct totals, but I can't figure how to summarise the results (it lists 3 twice, for example) ...

```
(
        (SELECT col1 as num, COUNT(col1) AS CON1, null as CON2, null as CON3  FROM mytable t1
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT col2, COUNT(col2) AS CON2 FROM mytable GROUP BY col2)  t2
                     ON t1.col1 = t2.col2
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT col3, COUNT(col3) AS CON3 FROM mytable GROUP BY col3)  t3
                     ON t2.col2 = t3.col3
        GROUP BY t1.col1)

        UNION

       (SELECT col2 as num, null as CON1, COUNT(col2) AS CON2, null as CON3  FROM mytable t4
          left JOIN (SELECT col1, COUNT(col1) AS CON1 FROM mytable GROUP BY col1)  t5
                      ON t4.col2 = t5.col1
          left JOIN (SELECT col3, COUNT(col3) AS CON3 FROM mytable GROUP BY col3)  t6
                      ON t4.col2 = t6.col3

        GROUP BY t4.col2)

        UNION

         (SELECT col3 as num, null as CON1, null as CON2, COUNT(col3) AS CON3 FROM mytable t7
          left JOIN (SELECT col1, COUNT(col1) AS CON1 FROM mytable GROUP BY col1)  t8
                      ON t7.col3 = t8.col1
          left JOIN (SELECT col2, COUNT(col2) AS CON3 FROM mytable GROUP BY col2)  t9
                      ON t7.col3 = t9.col2

        GROUP BY t7.col3)
        )
```

RESULTS:

```
num     CON1    CON2    CON3
1        3      
2                1  
2        2      
3                1  
3        1  
4                1
5                        1
5                1  
6                        2
7                        1
8                        1
9                1  
10               1  
15                       1
```

... Anyone?

SQL TEST:  https://sqltest.net/#979886

Comment: The url is just for testing. Does the code not work in Access?  If it errors post what in these comments?